# Docusign Salesforce Logout/switch account

Tags: salesforce, logout, docusignapi

We am working on a docusign project, our sandbox is connected to our DocuSign production org. I would like to connect it to a sanbox instead.

Can anyone help me where I can change the docuSign account in a salesforce sandbox.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps :

In the SF Sandbox org:

1. Use Setup->Create->Tabs to create a tab for the DocuSign Account
   Configuration object.
2. Open the DocuSign Account Configuration Tab and pick “Go”. There
   should be 0 or 1 object If there is one, then delete it.
3. Go to the DocuSign Admin Tab but don’t perform the setup steps. This
   creates a new DocuSign Account Configuration object.
4. Go to the DocuSign Account Configuration tab, open the single
   object, edit it and change the environment dropdown to point to the
   DS  environment you want to use (Preview, Demo), then pick save.
5. Go to the DocuSign Admin tab and configure the connection to DS
   using creds for that DS envrionment.